# Installing Xerox Phaser 3300 from CD - Do not have permissions

Tags: permissions, xerox

I am looking to configure my scanner, Xerox Phaser 3300MFP for use on Ubuntu 12.10. I am already able to print, but would like to use scanning to computer capability. I tried installing the software for my Phaser 3300 from the CD within XEROX_MFP\Linux\install.sh and by selecting "Open Auto Run Prompt" and I receive "You are not authorized to install the driver package. Only user with root privileges is allowed to do this. Installation cannot be completed now.

I then installed it using the sudo command, but now when trying to select the configuration utility on my desktop called "Xerox Unified Driver Configuator" I receive "There was an error launching the application. Details: Failed to execute child process "/opt/Xerox/mfp/bin/Configurator" (Permission denied)

I would like to get this scanner configured for use, but just not sure how to do so. Please advise. Do I need to launch this configuator using the sudo command? If so, I am not sure how to do that.

Please keep in mind I am new to Linux. As much as I hate to admit, I was raised on MS-DOS and Windows, even though they are really the same thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

If its a configuration file then you'd go with

sudo nano < path to file name . >

if you  want it in a GUI way then

gksudo gedit

remember that you have to execute them from terminal .